# Chrome "Save to PDF" margins background-color?

Tags: css, google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation

When printing to PDF in Google Chrome ("Save to PDF" virtual printer), there's an option to set margins for every page in inches // cm. However, by default they are always white. Is there a way to change color to blue, or use background-image?

What I've tried:

1. Ensured all background graphics are printed:

   ```
   @media print and (color) {
     * {
       -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
       print-color-adjust: exact;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Tried to set bg-color for @page attribute:

   ```
   @page {
      size: 7in 10in;
      margin: 1in;
   }
   ```
3. Tried to set bg color for every element on page: html, body, #content .

[This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/#generated-content-and-paged-media) shows an example, how to affect margins areas with footnotes:

```
@page:right{ 
  @bottom-left {
    margin: 10pt 0 30pt 0;
    border-top: .25pt solid #666;
    content: "My book";
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #333;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Also I've tried to inspect chrome build-in PDF previewer and found a string:

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="chrome://print/190/0/print.pdf" stream-url="chrome://print/190/0/print.pdf" headers="" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="0" top-level-url="undefined">
```

However, it's a bit tricky to modify `background-color` though it's already loaded and rendered. And I'm not sure, if it affects resulted PDF or just preview:

[image: Chrome PDF viewer dev tools state]

Any other options? This feature is rather critical for me, so I'm ready for memory hotpatching or even rebuilding Chromium from source if needed at least.

**Target platform:** Win 10 x64

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Can it be achieved by @media print{   @page{ }   } CSS?? Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There exist no direct way, but you can fake it:

Goto Format > Page.

Set the margin to 0cm. Ignore printer warning.
Set the background to your favorite color in tab Area.
Goto tab Borders and define a border in the same color. On that tab use the setting "Spacing to Contents" to fake the margins.